# Problems with centering elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a function to center an element in the middle of the screen from an user:

```
function positionElmentAtCenterOfUserWindow(elementId){

    var userBrowserWidth = $(window).width();
    var userBrowserHeight = $(window).height();
    var elementWidth = elementId.width();
    var elementHeight = elementId.height();
    var marginRight = (userBrowserWidth - elementWidth) / 2 +'px';
    var marginTop = (userBrowserHeight - elementHeight) / 2 +'px';

    console.log(userBrowserWidth+'-'+elementWidth+' * '+userBrowserHeight+'-'+elementHeight);
    elementId.css('position','absolute');
    elementId.css('top',marginTop);
    elementId.css('right',marginRight);

}
```

When the DOM is ready I launch this function on my presentation .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    positionElmentAtCenterOfUserWindow($("#presentation"));

});
```

The size of the user window is always returned right but elementWidth and elementHeight are changing over refresh from the page, resulting in hazardous behavior.

This can be tested on my website directle at: idealmenu.ch

Comment: Why would you need to do all that to center an element?

Comment: Because i will use later this function after editing the html from an element to re-position it correctly.

Comment: Are they pictures that might interfer with the width/height calculation ?

Comment: Make sure that you assign your elements the `position: absolute` CSS property in your CSS. I know you are setting it in your JavaScript, but it doesn't default to `position: absolute`. Also, set `left` and `top` to 0.

Comment: No, my element contain only html(<p><h2>) and text.

Comment: In any case, it seems to work on your site. What's broken?

Comment: @crush: the positioning is not the problem because is is working, but only the calculation of the boy size.

Comment: @isherwood: with chrome, when you refresh the box is sometimes moving at the bottom right. With console.log result: 1920-1904 * 638-211 instead of 1920-600 * 638-347 (for my screen).

Comment: I'd bet money that it is the problem.

Comment: Use only CSS, don't trust JS to get the correct screen width. Here this seems to be working, i will make a fiddle now.  {margin: 20% auto auto;}

Comment: @crush haha, maybe but how can it not happend all the times? Would maybe the DOM not ready be?

Comment: @K4trix You should make a jsfiddle demo. No one wants to click through to your website.

Comment: @crush Nice website, but dosent work with Jquery and Php, not?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with your question. It does work with jQuery - look at the options on the left hand side.

Comment: crazy, with http://jsfiddle.net/bufeK/ this never fail -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in CSS if you don't care about IE7/8

[jsfiddle.net/W26mt](http://jsfiddle.net/W26mt/)

```
#presentation {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -m-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: nop dont agree, this will not center my element. If my element is 20% width, with your code it will be at 30% from right and 50% from left ect..

Comment: It works perfectly well, % transforms are calculated on the size of the element and not the parent (such as widths are) - http://jsfiddle.net/W26mt/

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong: Definition and Usage
For absolutely positioned elements, the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right of the left edge of its containing element (parent). (from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp)

Comment: You are almost correct, absolutely positioned elements are relative to the closest relatively positioned parent. left:50%; and top:50%; will centre the top, left corner of the element within its closest relative parent. The -50%,-50% transform will then move the element left and up RELATIVE TO ITS OWN DIMENSIONS. Again, see my example ....  jsfiddle.net/W26mt

Comment: @K4trix Never use w3schools.com as a reference.

Comment: @michael Nevermind, dit test it only with 3 first line, seems to work fine ty.

Answer (score 0):

This does essentially the same thing. If anything, you'd use scripting to calculate the top and margin-top values to accommodate varying height. No window size values required.

```
#presentation {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;
}
```

Comment: Yep, but this css will work only until the size form my element doesn't change. I would like to be able to use it after loading html in some of my elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ha! I've made this function my own for a project. It uses pure Javascript. Have fun coding!

```
function positionElmentAtCenterOfUserWindow(elementId){
 var main = document.getElementById('elementId');
 var wi=main.offsetWidth;
 var he=main.offsetHeight;
 var marginleft = wi / 2;
 var margintop = he / 2;
 main.style.marginLeft="-" + marginleft;
 main.style.marginTop="-" + margintop;
 main.style.position="absolute";
 main.style.left="50%";
 main.style.top="50%"
}
```

Comment: thanks, very similar to mine, but interested in finding what's wrong with my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS to center divs in the middle of the screen. Works like a GEM, even in ie8

```
#yourDiv{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Same remark here: Yep, but this css will work only until the size form my element doesn't change. I would like to be able to use it after loading html in some of my elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Wbykp/1/][1](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbykp/1/)

Remove the JS code and apply this CSS.

```
#sectionCentre
{
   margin: 20% auto auto;    
}
```

JS might not always get the correct width/height, in other words, you might be able to calculate the margin manually due to other DOM element may occupy some space.

Hope this helps:
The 20% is because of your div block height, it's the space from the roof until the head of the element.

I used `auto` to let the browser decide for it self regarding the `width` (left and right space) depending on the total available space.

I'm not using auto for height because, well, it will not work, the if the length of your document increase, you don't want the article div to be down there out of reach.